# Injecting custom CSS into WP Admin login popup iframe

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, iframe, xenforo

So I am running a bridge plugin that hooks Xenforo forum into Wordpress, with single sign-on (User authentication is entirely handled by Xenforo, and all WP login/registrations etc are redirected to matching Xenforo links).

However in wp-admin, upon cookie expiration a popup iframe appears with a login form, though with this bridge it literally loads the entire Xenforo's login page.

Because I'm trying to modify the display of this page w/o using external changes to Xenforo, I suppose the only way would be to inject custom CSS into the iframe popup and use display:none on all the Xenforo elements I don't want. Basically I don't want an entire web page loading in the popup, but just a simple login form like the default WP form.

I've scanned dozens of files and can't locate the WP file that produces this popup window, any help?

Could accomplishing something like this be included in a plugin file or adding filters, w/o making changes to WP core files?

Comment: I believe it uses the default wp-login.php in a lightbox. You can use the following function in your themes function.php file to add a custom stylesheet to the admin/login pages,  
  `// Custom Wordpress Dashboard CSS
function myC_dashboard() {  
    wp_enqueue_style('scg-dashboard-theme', '/assets/themes/THEME/_inc/css/dashboard.css');  
}  
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'myC_dashboard');  
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'myC_dashboard');`

Comment: Perfect!! Forgot to mention using functions.php somehow wouldv'e been ideal, and you nailed it - thanks a ton :-).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it uses the default wp-login.php in a lightbox. You can use the following function in your themes function.php file to add a custom stylesheet to the admin/login pages,

`// Custom Wordpress Dashboard CSS function myC_dashboard() {     wp_enqueue_style('scg-dashboard-theme', '/assets/themes/THEME/_inc/css/dashboard.css'); } add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'myC_dashboard'); add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'myC_dashboard');`

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php [enqueue the the stylesheet and scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) to add custom code.

Example for css:

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
        wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

If jQuery is used, Please do not enqueue jQuery core file since WordPress already has it.